# Show splash screen only when launching the app from launcher

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I have my `SplashActivity` like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    Handler Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1500);

        Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    }
}
```

And its declaration in `AndroidManifext.xml` like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Splash"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
        android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="brokenhearts.ml"
            android:scheme="http"
            android:pathPattern="/*"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="brokenhearts.ml"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:pathPattern="/*"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.brokenhearts.ml"
            android:scheme="http"
            android:pathPattern="/*"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.brokenhearts.ml"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:pathPattern="/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm using WebViews in my app. The problem is, whenever a user taps on a link of my website in some other activity of my app, it starts from `SplashActivity` all over again. That's in a way correct, as that's where I have added the intents. However, I'd like to know if there is any other way with this setup to show the splash screen only when the app is launched from the launcher or from the URL intent (when the app is not running) and not when the URL intent is triggered when the app is already running in the foreground.

If it's not possible with this set-up, what's the other way I can go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if appLinkData is null then display SplashScreen else start MainScreen

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    Handler Handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

         Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData;
        if(appLinkAction!=null)
        appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();

        if(appLinkData!=null)
        {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
        finish();
         return;
        }else
        {

        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            },
                1500);

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error: Variable 'appLinkData' might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider overriding the `onNewIntent` life-cycle function of Android in your case. This will handle any prior creation to this `SplashActivity`, with a new intent along with it. Here is an example:

From the other activity of your app where you launch the `SplashActivity` again you might need to start the activity like this.

```
public class OtherActivityContainingWebView extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("url", "www.your-website-or-any-other-data-to-be-passed-to-splash-activity");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

You need to have an `onNewIntent` function in your `SplashActivity` like this.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        // Your current code goes here ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        // Do something with the value passed from the other activity
        // Then launch the Main Activity from here.

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!